# Erro ao usar o android no eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Estou começando a aprender a programar com android e logo de cara me deparei com este erro, o que fazer?

Apresenta este erro no console:

```
[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Versions found are:

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Path: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\EclipseProjects\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     Length: 1074044

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     SHA-1: 33b27a8d2a5b87e6eb6c60e87a5374ffbfeacc3a

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Path: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\EclipseProjects\TransicaoEntreTelas\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     Length: 1422188

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     SHA-1: 1dc1f63cee098b27db60b9a2833fd7ca58f89636

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Versions found are:

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Path: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\EclipseProjects\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     Length: 1074044

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     SHA-1: 33b27a8d2a5b87e6eb6c60e87a5374ffbfeacc3a

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Path: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\EclipseProjects\TransicaoEntreTelas\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     Length: 1422188

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     SHA-1: 1dc1f63cee098b27db60b9a2833fd7ca58f89636

[2016-03-25 18:09:34 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Versions found are:

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Path: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\EclipseProjects\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     Length: 1074044

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     SHA-1: 33b27a8d2a5b87e6eb6c60e87a5374ffbfeacc3a

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Path: C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\EclipseProjects\TransicaoEntreTelas\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     Length: 1422188

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas]     SHA-1: 1dc1f63cee098b27db60b9a2833fd7ca58f89636

[2016-03-25 18:09:35 - TransicaoEntreTelas] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Segue a imagem do erro abaixo:

[image: Erro eclipse com android]

Comment: Cole o texto do erro, ver por imagem fica dificil.

Comment: Pronto, copiei o erro que da no console. Fico no aguardo. Grato

Comment: @Guilherme não use o eclipse. Para android a ferramente que possui todo o suporte é o Android Studio. http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

tal como o Caique Oliveira mencionou, se estas a comecar com o Android usa o Android Studio. Pois é a suportada pelo Google desde o ano passado, e incorpora o sistema Gradle para compilar e gerir os teus projectos e libs.

O que me parece é que tens dois projectos no Eclipse ambos com a mesma lib (android-support-v4.jar ) e estão a entrar em conflito um com a outra.

Fix simples: remove uma das libs que deve funcionar.
Fix melhor: instala o android studio e gradle e vais deixar de ter esses problemas :)

Happy coding :D